# Lifetime of a FacesComponent

Tags: jsf

I just declare a simple FacesComponent to use it with a composite component.

```
@FacesComponent("fc/myFacesComponent")
public class MyFacesComponent extends UINamingContainer {
   ...
}
```

Now I'm asking myself, how long is the lifetime of the FacesComponent annotated class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A component itself will live from the initial build view (first phase of JSF lifecycle) till the render view phase where the component tree gets built a second time.
But I am wondering if you actually wanted to ask something else. Maybe about the lifetime of managed beans?

Comment: No, thats actually I wanted to know. Many Thanks.

Comment: The component tree doesn't get built a second time during the render response phase at all.

Comment: Sure, at least once again since the view can change during the previous phases and events. And of course when the view ID changed. Check MyFace's org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(). A second buildView process is even required at the render phase when the view ID has not changed because the tree can change when you there are JSTL tags such as c:if on the view or if using dynamic includes (ui:include with EL expression at src-attribute).

Answer (score -1):

@FacesComponent("fc/myFacesComponent") life time is Reuest Scope and we can not change it.

If you want you can inject beans(Session) in it and get the state and show it to the component.

Backing beans are either JSF managed beans OR CDI Weld Beans.

Thanks,
Roshan